# logback, Method printStackTrace() is executed after meeting with method log.debug()

Tags: java, log4j, logback

Method `e.printStackTrace()` is executed after the method `log.debug()`.

maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.24</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5</version>
</dependency>`
```

my code

```
@Slf4j
public class SleepTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create a thread named "t0" and start it.
        Thread t0 = new Thread(()->{
            log.debug("running...");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            log.debug("continue");
        },"t0");
        t0.start();
        //interrupt "t0"
        t0.interrupt();
    }
}
```

output

```
00:09:48 [t0] [DEBUG] com.codingcube.introduction.SleepTest - running...
00:09:48 [t0] [DEBUG] com.codingcube.introduction.SleepTest - bug
00:09:48 [t0] [DEBUG] com.codingcube.introduction.SleepTest - continue
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.codingcube.introduction.SleepTest.lambda$main$0(SleepTest.java:14)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

In the code, `log.debug("continue");` comes after `e.printStackTrace();`, but the output comes before it.

This problem does not occur when I run part of the code in the main thread.

```
@Slf4j
public class SleepTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.debug("running...");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            throw new InterruptedException();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        log.debug("continue");
    }
}
```

output

```
00:16:05 [main] [DEBUG] com.codingcube.introduction.SleepTest - running...
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at com.codingcube.introduction.SleepTest.main(SleepTest.java:13)
00:16:06 [main] [DEBUG] com.codingcube.introduction.SleepTest - continue
```

and the problem does not occur when I remove the first log

```
@Slf4j
public class SleepTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create a thread named "t0" and start it.
        Thread t0 = new Thread(()->{
            //log.debug("running...");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            log.debug("continue");
        },"t0");
        t0.start();

        //interrupt "t0"
        t0.interrupt();
    }
}
```

output

```
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.codingcube.introduction.SleepTest.lambda$main$0(SleepTest.java:15)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
00:18:17 [t0] [DEBUG] com.codingcube.introduction.SleepTest - continue
```

Answer (score 1):

`e.printStackTrace()` is executed before `log.debug("continue")`

The first one writes to stderr and the second one writes probably to stdout.
The output order depends on the order the two streams are flushed and closed.

Try to replace `e.printStackTrace()` with `log.debug("exception",e)`